# pip install on local module failing with Cython extension

Tags: python, pip, cython

I'm working on a module that relies on Cython extensions, and when I run a `pip install -vvv .` I get a lot of output that ends with not being able to find an `__init__.py` file to copy into the bdist. I've determined the module builds just fine if I remove the Cython dependency from the `setup.py` so the Cython component doesn't build with the module, and I've also determined that the `.so` file builds just find when I run the build.

I'm assuming I'm doing something silly in my `setup.py`, but I'm not sure what. Any pointers for what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

File structure is:

```
.
|____LICENSE
|____CONTRIBUTING.rst
|____pyproject.toml
|____setup.py
|____tox.ini
|____AUTHORS.rst
|____setup.cfg
|____README.rst
|____CHANGELOG.rst
|____src
| |____UtilsModule
| | |______init__.py
| | |____dependencies
| | | |____hello_world.pyx
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____Library2
| | | |____hello_world.py
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____Library
| | | |____TestLibrary.py
| | | |______init__.py
```

Full working example module here: https://github.com/sdwebb/cython_template

Full `setup.py` here:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

import numpy

from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(
        name="dependencies.hello_world",
        sources=["src/UtilsModule/dependencies/hello_world.pyx"], 
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    ),
]


setup(
    name='cython_template',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        setup(use_scm_version={"version_scheme": "no-guess-dev"})
    except:  # noqa
        print(
            "\n\nAn error occurred while building the project, "
            "please ensure you have the most updated version of setuptools, "
            "setuptools_scm and wheel with:\n"
            "   pip install -U setuptools setuptools_scm wheel\n\n"
        )
        raise
```

edit:  I should add that when the build finishes, there's a working `.so` file inside the `lib.[your environment info here]/dependencies` directory inside `build/`, but no `__init__.py`. Here's the whole `build` folder that gets created:

```
.
|____lib.macosx-13.3-arm64-cpython-310
| |____dependencies
| | |____hello_world.cpython-310-darwin.so
| |____UtilsModule
| | |______init__.py
| | |____dependencies
| | | |____hello_world.pyx
| | | |______init__.py
| | | |____hello_world.c
| | |____Library2
| | | |____hello_world.py
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____Library
| | | |____TestLibrary.py
| | | |______init__.py
|____bdist.macosx-13.3-arm64
|____lib
| |____UtilsModule
| | |______init__.py
| | |____dependencies
| | | |____hello_world.pyx
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____Library2
| | | |____hello_world.py
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____Library
| | | |____TestLibrary.py
| | | |______init__.py
|____temp.macosx-13.3-arm64-cpython-310
| |____src
| | |____UtilsModule
| | | |____dependencies
| | | | |____hello_world.o
```